# Single thread app is holding messages from other queue while processing one message -RMQ

Tags: c#, easynetq, rmq

I am facing one issue and adding the details here.
I have multiple Windows services consuming RMQ queues. I am using topshelf for Windows service and EastnetQ for RMQ subscription. Prefetch count is 1 for all consumers.
I am publishing the message to the queue through my web application. All are through c#.

[See Overall flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA9cT.png)

My issue is that Service Shared is a single-thread application. In my case, ServiceShared is consuming one message from each queue at a time, but processing one after another.
It's holding the message from each queue. But actual message processing is one by one. Due to that other individual consumers cannot process the messages.

I checked the connection and channels and I can see multiple channels for the Service shared and messages are in unack state.

[See the image: how RMQ channels are unack messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdv40.png)

How I can avoid holding messages from other queues until the current one has finished its processing?

Comment: Once consumer received message, immediately save it somewhere else, and release the message before actually processing?

Comment: producer-consumer problem https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem&oldid=997247765

Comment: It is not a producer-consumer issue.  Its all about different consumers. ServiceCommon is a single threaded service and it internally consumes 2 different RMQ queues. But it will process the message one at a time. So if both queue has messages, then it will take message  from both queue and will process it one by one. So the second one is actually on hold until the first one is processed. Since its holding the message from other queue, individual service cannot consume it

Comment: maybe a drawing will tell more than words - if you want to add it to the question make sure to also tag it with algorithm to get the right audience

Comment: Updated the description with images